# Redirect All Sub Pages to Same Place on New URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a blog from one domain to another. I have setup the URL structure, so it matches for all pages. Essentially it will be going from olddomain.com to newdomain.com/blog/ (for example http://www.olddomain.org/2013/01/blog-name/ to http://www.newdomain.org/blog/2013/01/blog-name/). What is the best way to do this via .htaccess? I have tried a few options that I have found online, but they only seem to redirect the homepage and not all the subpages as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It worked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.org/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```